# A 9 kW heater has an efficiency of 85%. How much power is lost over 4 hours use?

Tags: power

I have output power = efficiency x input power which is 7650 W. 1350 W is lost times by 4 is 5400 W over 4 hours but that's incorrect.

I'm doing a multiple choice practice test and the 4 possible answers are 12.5 W, 6.18 W, 12.6 W and 5.28 W. I'm not sure if I was working it out wrong or maybe the test has an error with the answers displayed?

The correct answer (according to the test) is 6.18 W.

Comment: So.. Can you tell how much energy is used by the heater in one hour in total?

Comment: Welcome! Please show your calculations so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: i have output power = efficiency x input power which is 7650W.. 1350W is lost times by 4 is 5400W over 4 hours but thats incorrect..

Comment: How do you know it is incorrect? Looks correct to me.

Comment: basically im doing a multiple choice practice test and the 4 possible answers are 12.5W, 6.18W, 12.6W and 5.28W ? im not sure if i was working it out wrong or maybe the test has an error with the answers displayed?

Comment: If the answers have units of `W`, it is definitely wrong.

Comment: ok thank you for that i will let my tutor know

Comment: 9kW heater spends 9kWh of energy every hour. In four hours, how much will that be? If 15% of that is wasted, how much will that be?

Comment: 5.4kW. its just on the test none of the answers match up to my calculation which is what im getting confused with

Comment: If the question was 'how much **energy** is lost over 4 hours', I could understand it, but power over 4 hours in nonsense

Comment: thank you neil and sorry about that!

Comment: Is the original test in English or is this just a bad translation problem?

Comment: yes its in english and the correct answer is (according to the test) is 6.18W

Comment: Maybe the question is intentionally asked in this way. What if the teacher wants to see if you are aware or careful enough? What if the 1st student who catches the mistake will get A+? I can't see any other reason of asking this meaningless question. It's like "How long a **speed** will you **travel** if your speed is 60 miles?"

Comment: The correct answer is most definitely NOT 6.18W

Comment: _"1350W is lost times by 4 is 5400W"_ Here is a unit problem. You don't multiply by 4, you multiply by 4 hours and the resulting multiplication of W x h is Wh.

Comment: If the question assumes that 9kW power to be the output power then the lost power will be (9/.85 - 9)=1.588 kW. After 4 hours, the lost energy will be 6.353 Wh, which is close to the true (???) answer.

Comment: @RohatKılıç You multiply by the efficiency, not divide.

Comment: If 9kW is the output power, 9/0.85 will give you the input power (10.588kW)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Please read the first section of my comment again: **If it's assumed that the 9kW power to be output...** You divide by efficiency to find the input power, which is 10.5888, then subtract the 9kW to find the lost power.

Comment: This question is messed up in more ways than one, or even two. Units don't match. Digits don't match. Magnitudes don't match.

Comment: Are there perhaps also multiple questions and you have to figure out the question to which the answer is "6.18 W" ? Anyway, voting to close because this is turning into a typical Wh-meme talk. Also it is a pretty bad heater, if it has less than 100% efficiency.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I see, right. We don't know what 9kW is referring to

Comment: no problem thank you all for your help, my tutor has already signed off but i have emailed him about this question, i finished up with 36/40 and this was one of the Q's i got incorrect. there is no feedback at the end and so i was just going through them to where i went wrong and was stuck with this one, thank you everyone

Comment: Power (in W) is instantaneous. It doesn’t depend on time. You lose 1350 W of power at any time the heater is on, whether it’s on for one minute or for 2 years. Energy (in J, but more likely here in Wh, not W), is the product of power by time. Over 4 hours, you’ll have lost 5400 Wh of energy.

Comment: @RohatKılıç kWh, not Wh.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it a trick question?
First, power is an instantaneous measurement. Power x time is energy.

Second, it is a heater.  How can it be only 85% efficient? What happens to the other 15%?  Is it "wasted" as heat?  Is some work done that is not converted to heat?

Think about it. A motor may be 60% efficient because 40% is wasted as heat.  An LED may be 25% efficient at converting power to lumens and losing the other 75% to heat. So, how can a heater be anything less than 100% efficient?  Even if that heater is creating some red light, the light will eventually get absorbed by something and turn to heat (I can assure you that a heater is not making 15% light as a by-product.  Even if it is homework, you should call out your instructor on this one.

Comment: It is also buzzing and vibrating :)

Comment: It could be a water-heater where the wasted energy would be heating the air

Comment: Good argument that about the 85% efficiency! I was going to comment on that, too.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen It would be a very very bad designed heater, then. 15% energy used NOT to heat the water? Just immerse the heating element (suitably electrically insulated) in the water and the only way it has to heat the air is via the connecting wires. There is no way they would "waste" 15% of power heating the "wrong" fluid.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yep! And probably emitting some high intensity X-rays in the process, just to be sure! :-D

Comment: Guys, just let's take it as an artificial question. Well, not a good one though. Or a tricky one, as stated.

Comment: I suppose it could be a *really* bad heat pump with a coefficient of performance of 0.85...

Comment: @LorenzoDonati--Codidact.com Typical propane or natural gas water heaters have an efficiency of around 95%. Electric water heaters can be very close to 100%.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I gave it for granted we are talking about electrical gear on this site, so I didn't consider any other kind of heater (otherwise the question would be utterly off-topic here). You should work quite hard *not* to make an electrical heater nearly 100% efficient. Of course (that's why the sarcasm in one of my comments) you can always make a tool that converts electrical energy to any other form of energy (X-rays? Sound?) and consider the wasted heat as the output. So an audio power amplifier is a very inefficient ambient heater (you get lots of unwanted noise) :-)

Answer (score 7):

Another question: is the 9kW the *input* power or the *output* power?

If the OUTPUT of the heater is 9 kW and its input is higher (say 10545 W), we get 9000/10545 = 0.85%. (more or less)

In that case, (10545-9000)*4hours yields 6.18 kilowatt-hours.

But, as presented, of course, the question is hosed.

Comment: I think you have solved the mystery here.